# Emacs subshell (M-x shell) not autocompleting shell aliases

Tags: shell, emacs

I have aliases defined on my `.zshrc` file that I commonly use when I am on a `gnome-terminal`. However, when I am on `M-x shell` on Emacs, the autocompletion does not find them (even though they still work).

Is this a limitation of the Emacs subshell? Are there any known workarounds to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That mode does not provide a fully functional terminal to the subshell.  Use `M-x ansi-term` instead.